# Openswan connecting to multiple right subnets not working

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec

I'm trying to use Openswan (version 2.6.37) to connect an IPsec VPN from my local network to a remote site. Everything works fine when I just want to connect to a single subnet on the remote site. However, the remote site also has an extra subnet that I want to access.

This is my configuration:

```
conn myConn
        type=tunnel
        left=192.168.139.14
        leftsubnet=192.168.139.0/24
        leftxauthclient=yes
        right=X.X.X.X
        rightsubnet=172.16.1.0/24
        keyexchange=ike
        auth=esp
        authby=secret
        phase2alg=3des-sha1
        pfs=yes
```

When I replace `rightsubnet` with `rightsubnets`, like so:

```
rightsubnets={172.16.1.0/24 192.168.3.0/24}
```

...then the connection is created successfully but only the last subnet in the list is available. Any attempts to ping anything on the `172.16.1.0` subnet fails. If I swap the order of the subnets around then I can ping `172.16.1.X` but can't ping anything on the other subnet. It's as if Openswan is only using the last subnet in the list to create a connection.

Am I doing something wrong here?

A little bit of extra information that I neglected to mention (although I'm not sure it's relevant): My Openswan client is behind a router using NAT and I have `nat_traversal=yes` in my `ipsec.conf` file.

Comment: Do you use VLANs? I had almost exactly the same problem and the issue was a VLAN error

Comment: Have you tried making two security associations, one for each subnet?

Comment: @Tyke, no I'm not using VLANs. My OpenSwan client is behind a router using NAT though - I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @gimmesudo: I tried duplicating my configuration above for a new connection (`connection myConn2`), with everything identical except for the `rightsubnet`. When I use `ipsec auto --up myConn` I can ping 172.168.1.X. When I try to bring up the second connection (`ipsec auto --up myConn2`), I can ping 192.168.3.X but the first connection dies completely.

Comment: For conneting as a client on many IPSec routers (like Cisco), You'll simplier to use [`vpnc`](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/) !

Comment: Facing the exact same issue. Did you fix this and are you able to recall what the issue was?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the usual [separator for the multiple subnets is a comma](https://lists.openswan.org/pipermail/users/2009-May/016573.html), but at least openswan-2.6.32 works with spaces too.

Interesting information should be logged to `/var/log/secure` which could contain clues why it isn't working. Also post the output of `ip x s sh` and `ip x p sh`.

Comment: If you got here trying to switch from single host to multiple hosts, pay attention that the key for multiple subnets is in plural (`rightsubnet*s*`) instead of singular.

Answer (score 1):

Make `conn` section configuration for each subnets on BOTH endpoints of the tunnel. Only one of them (the first started) will start a SA negotiation, the second (or more) will only make a new SPD of the further subnets.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this as the remote endpoint is a third-party FortiGate router (not running OpenSwan). I'm starting to wonder if the problem may be related to the router not being able to cope with multiple tunnels between the same endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `rightsubnets` you have to use `leftsubnets` as well, not `leftsubnet`. Even if there's only one subnet on that side.
The [`ipsec.conf` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ipsec.conf) doesn't do a great job of explaining this, but it's there.

I had the similar problems for months and just found the answer in [openswan multiple subnets routing issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/571352/openswan-multiple-subnets-routing-issue).

Comment: Not the case. leftsubnets={singletone}, should be identical to leftsubnet=. (I wrote the code)

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me using libeswan 3.15.  My left had a single subnet and the right had several.  If I configured the left using leftsubnet= and the right using rightsubnets={} then only the last rightsubnet actually connected.  Once I configured the left to use leftsubnets={} with the one subnet, it connected to all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a bug in OpenSwan where the subnets list needs an extra comma at the end to work correctly.  Try:

```
rightsubnets={172.16.1.0/24,192.168.3.0/24,}
```

Note the extra comma at the end.

Comment: That is not the case, none of the test cases or examples have an extra comma.

Answer (score -3):

It should be like this

```
rightsubnets={172.16.1.0/24,192.168.3.0/24}
```

Use a comma (`,`) and not a space to separate entries.

Comment: That seems to be what the answer from two years ago is saying.